# Delete microfeed entries

Tags: sharepoint-server

I'm looking for a solution to delete entries directly in microfeed list. Trying that (doesn't matter if I use an account with with "Manage Social Data" permission on User Profile Service Application or simply the system account) leads to a permission denied message. Doesn't matter if it's a base post or a reply or somewhat. The items are not on hold (there is no regualation for that either).

"Deleting" those items via web part works as it should (or let's say, the deleted posts do not show up again). But the items seem to be still there in the microfeed list.

For some reasons items older than x months or written by deactivated/deleted accounts have to be deleted.

So, any suggestions how to deal this? I didn't find any more information but maybe some of you have some more to share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the actual design of the SharePoint, we can't delete others post from the Micro feed and even i can't delete my own post from the microfeed list. And per my test, I think that  Microfeed list can be deleted only by deactivating the SiteFeed feature.